# What is the maximal value that we can have after 99 operations?

Tags: combinatorics, maxima-minima, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-proofs

we begin with the numbers $1,\frac{1}2 ,\frac{1}3,\ldots \frac{1}{100}$ written in a board.
We do the following operation : we delete $2$ numbers $a$ and $b$ from the board , and we remplace them with the number $a+b+ab$. what is the maximal value that we can have in the board after $99$ operations

here is what i think
if we have for example numbers $a$ and $b$ and $c$ in the board if we choose $a$ and $b$ first we will have two numbers , $(a+ab+b,c)$ then we will have the number $a+b+c+ab+bc+ac+abc$ 
and if we choose $a$ and $c$ first we will have $a+c+ac$ and $b$ , then $a+b+c+ab+bc+ac+abc$ ...... i think that whatever numbers we choose  we will have the same number at the end , but we need to prove it , and we need to know the number that will remain.

Comment: Show that the operation $a\star b=a+b+ab$ is commutative and associative. This proves that the order you do the operations does not matter.

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be $99$?

Comment: If $n<99$, then you will not have enough values and the process would not make sense. If $n>99$, then you can wind up with $\dfrac{1}{n}$ left, which would be the minimal number. If $n=99$, then as @MikeEarnest suggests, you can show that the operation is commutative and associative to show that the order of operations does not matter.

Comment: Are you looking for a maximal or minimal value?

Comment: n=100 m looking for the maximal one

Comment: The answer is 99. You can use @MikeEarnest's hint to see why.

Comment: Inthis case try to produce larger and larger numbers starting from the left.  You’ll obtain $2,3,4,\dots$.

Comment: i cnt get to the solution plz help me

Comment: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=2$, $2+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}=3$ and so on.

Comment: but i dnt knw how to prove that this operation is commutative and associative

Comment: The hints above are good. An alternative way of solving it is to first show, with $a\star b \equiv a+b+ab$, that $a_1\star a_2 \star \ldots \star a_n = (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_n+1) - 1$

Comment: i know that i should prove that but hooow ??!!

Comment: Commutative means $a\star b = b\star a$ and associative means $a\star (b\star c) = (a\star b)\star c$. Simply insert the definition $(a\star b) \equiv  (a+b+ab)$ and show the left hand side equals the right hand side in these properties. For the rest use induction. For example the formula I mention: if $a_1\star \cdots \star a_n = -1 + \prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i)$ then $(a_1\star \cdots \star a_n) \star a_{n+1} = (a_1\star \cdots\star a_n) + a_{n+1} + a_{n+1}(a_1\star \cdots\star a_n) = \ldots$ Insert and simplify.

Comment: @Winther but from where did u come with this formula

Comment: Do it for a few small $n$ (say $2,3$), notice the pattern: $a_1\star a_2 = (a_1+1)(a_2+1) - 1$ and $a_1\star a_2\star a_3 = (a_1+1)(a_2+1)(a_3+1)-1$ etc., prove it via induction. This is a common way to approach such problems. That being said, to solve this particular problem it's probably easier to notice as said above that $1\star 1/2 = 2$ and $2\star 1/3 = 3$ and in general $(n-1) \star 1/n = n$

Comment: so the result is 100